# Proving $x ≡ y \pmod n $ if $x^a ≡ y^a \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to prove $x ≡ y \pmod n $ if $x^a ≡ y^a \pmod n?$
We assume $a$ and $φ(n)$ are relatively prime and $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

I have no idea how to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: In the future, please put the question in the question body, not just the title.

Comment: Hint:  if you assume that $x,n$ are coprime then $x$ has an inverse $\pmod n$ and we'd have $\left(x^{-1}y\right)^a\equiv 1 $

Comment: @lulu  congruent to $1-$...? Sorry i am unsure where you are trying to go from there

Comment: The dash is an artifact of the site format.  I am just saying that, assuming $x$ has an inverse, $\left( x^{-1}y\right)^a\equiv 1 \pmod n$.  What, then, are the possible orders of $x^{-1}y$?

Comment: @lulu all multiples and divisors of $a$?

Comment: @lulu But it doesn't say $x,n$ coprime, it says $x,y$ coprime.  Am I being dense (again)?

Comment: @saulspatz  correct.  My hint addresses a (critical) special case.  Having handled that case, one has to also consider the possibility that $x,n$ have a common factor (and get a contradiction).

Comment: @iphonex  Well, yes.  But it also has to be a divisor of $\varphi(n)$

Comment: @lulu does that imply $a = 1$ ?

Comment: No.  it implies that the order of $x^{-1}y\pmod n$ is $1$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We begin with:

Special case:  $\gcd(x,n)=1$.  In that case, $x$ has an inverse $\pmod n$ and we deduce that $$\left( x^{-1}y\right)^a\equiv 1 \pmod n$$

But then we know that the order of $x^{-1}y$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $\varphi(n)$, hence the order is $1$, hence $x^{-1}y\equiv 1 \pmod n$ which implies $x\equiv y \pmod n$ which is what we were trying to prove.

To conclude, suppose that $\gcd(x,n)=d>1$.  Then there is some prime $p$ which divides both $x$ and $n$.  But in that case we must have $$p\,|\,x^a-y^a\implies p\,|\,y^a\implies p\,|\,y$$

Whence $p\,|\,\gcd(x,y)$ but that contradicts the assumption that $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and we are done.